# How do you add a line break in a Label using LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-label

I've created a `Label` on a `Form`, but is too large to show it in one line, is it posible make a break line? I am using LWUIT on J2ME.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Label` is not make to break lines. Why don't you try with `TextArea`? It allows you to show multiline items.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextArea` instead of `Label` and disable the editable mode and create empty border to that `TextArea`. `Label` isn't allow multi line.

Comment: Both this and jmunoz answers are correct. I would personally add: textArea.setUIID("Label") instead of setting the border.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Label label = new Label(" ") and add it to the container.

Answer (score -2):

Create many labels and place them inside a `BoxLayout`(Y_AXIS) `Container`.